# How to insert an array in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uilabel

I'm making a game app, the general idea is that when you tap in the car you get 10 points, i've got a Label that must show the points made... And I have the array of points also. But I don't know how to connect them, should I use a IBAction?

Comment: You should watch lectures 1 and 2 from Stanford's iPad class on iTunes U.  I just started to watch them to learn about iOS development, and I think those alone would answer your question.

Comment: Shouldn't you sum up the points? I.e. the array (10p 10p, 10p) would show as 30p in the label?

Comment: Could you clarify what is the array composed of? I know that points, but what points? The player has only one sum of points, isn't he?

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to make the number, whatever it might be, show up in the label.  IBAction is for button presses... sounds like you want to use an Output.  If I were more experienced in iOS development, I'd be able to give you more info.  :)  Watch the classes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert an array into a label. Labels hold text (NSString values).

What do you want to put into the label, the total point score? (Which would be the sum of the values in your point array?)

If so, you need to add code to the method that increases the user's score to also update the score label.

You might have code like this:

```
- (void) addPointsToScore: (NSInteger) pointsToAdd;
{
  totalScore += pointsToAdd;
  scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", totalPoints];
}
```

That code does not deal with arrays, since you don't make it clear what you mean about arrays. It simply adds points to a score instance variable (totalScore) and then updates a scoreLabel label with the new score value, converted to a string.

Does that help?

Comment: Forget about the arrays, I was wrong... I was using an (IBAction)buttonPressed, when you tap in the button you get +10 points, but your method is way more elegant. Thanks!